# How do I fix: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: node.js, lambda, testcafe

I get the following error when running my E2E test through CLI, but it works locally.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined 
    at Object.promisify (internal/util.js:256:11) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Octopus\Applications\Staging\e2e\0.0.108\node_modules\testcafe\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\utils\promisified-functions.js:16:33) 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10) 
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) 
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) 
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) 
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17) 
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Octopus\Applications\Staging\e2e\0.0.108\node_modules\testcafe\node_modules\testcafe-hammerhead\lib\request-pipeline\file-request\base-resource.js:7:33)
```

I have updated npm, Node, testcafe and testcafe-hammerhead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an outdated Node.js version because of the [zlib.brotliCompress](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlibbrotlidecompressbuffer-options-callback) function evaluated as `undefined`.
Upgrade it up to 14.x and run your tests again.